# How to select a button and delete a grandparent div of that button when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This here is my code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn.btn-default.btn-lg.remove").click(function(){ 
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
```

```
      <div class="row lead"  style="margin-left:100px;color:red">
           <div class="col-md-2"><span style="color:red></div>
           <div class="col-md-2"><span style="color:red"></div>
           <div class="col-md-2"><span style="color:red"></div>
           <div class="col-md-2"><span style="color:red"></div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg remove"> </button> 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"></button>    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"></button>
               </div>
      </div>
```

I want the entire div to get deleted when the button of class="btn btn-default btn-lg remove" gets clicked. I cant use id because i am dynamically appending the above div using append jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn.btn-default.btn-lg.remove").click(function(){ 
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you just want to get one level higher?
This deletes the whole div "row lead".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".btn.btn-default.btn-lg.remove").click(function(){ 
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn.btn-default.btn-lg.remove").click(function(){ 
             $(this).closest(".row.lead").remove();
     });
});
```